# Linking / Synchronising SQL DB with MySQL DB

Tags: sql, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a need to access data in a MS SQL database from within in MySQL and would like to know my options. The data is held across various joined tables

Ideally I would like to mirror the database schema and data in MySQL so that it can be queried from within Wordpress.

The data is hotel information as seen here http://www.vrxstudios.com/advanced_search.aspx

The plan is to represent each hotel as a wordpress post.

Would it make sense to create a flat table in SQL and link this somehow in MySQL?

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move data from MS SQL Server to MySQL you could use SSIS routines to move the data. You could schedule the data import to happen as often has you need.

The simplest form would be a direct copy in schema structure from MS SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Once the schema is setup in MySQL would the SSIS routines maintain a mirror copy of the data from the MS SQL db?

Comment: You would have to create a SQL Agent schedule to move the data. It would not be a real time mirror.